# How to join dataframe without getting duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes like following:

```
df1

       id  salary
    0  1   1000
    1  2   2000

df2

       id  txn  age  gender
    0  1   6     23   M
    1  1   4     23   M
    2  2   10    31   F
    3  2   5     31   F
    4  2   8     31   F

I want to join the dataframes as following:

df3

       id  salary age  gender
    0  1   1000    23   M
    1  2   2000    31   F
```

I am using the following code but getting a total of 5 rows. However, I want only 2 rows like above dataframe

```py
d3 = pd.merge(d1, d2, on='id', how='left')
```

What is the correct way to join the dataframes without getting duplicates?

Comment: You receive 5 rowes because
id 1 from df1  --> sees  2 rows with id 1 in df2
and  
id 2 from df2 --> sees 3   times id 2 in  df2   
thus it will take all of them  --  
if you   remove the column  txn and drop the duplicate rows,  it will work

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates('id')[['id','age','gender']],
                on='id', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   id  salary  age gender
0   1    1000   23      M
1   2    2000   31      F
```